# Store Stripe payment history

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-5.4, strip

I have integrated stripe in to my application.
Now i want to store the payment history in to my database.
Using stripe APIs, i can create new subscription as well as update that subscription.
Now say i have one subscription for one month for $20 and after few days i am updating to sixmonth for $60. So as per stripe logs it will deduct $40 while updating plan.
I want to store all these payment process along with subscription periods in to my database.

How can i do that. Is that any API for it?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#when-to-use-webhooks) to get notification from Stripe whenever any `event` happen.**

So you need to create a webhook for [charge.succeeded](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-charge.succeeded). So that you can get notification for all the successful charges happen. You can get `amount`, `customer` data inside the `event` data which you can store to your DB. I assume you are already storing `subscription` along with `customer`, so that you can map `subscription` from `customer` data from `event` data.

Comment: I saw charge.succeeded webhook request and in that i could not found any details regarding subscription and customer. I mean they have not given any reference of subscription for which the charge has been deducted.

I need subscription , subscription period using which i can update my entries. FYI. i am making new entries for each subscription update.